# CakePHP: Load count of related Models with bindModel

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, model

I have two models in an 1:n relation and I just want to load the count of the related items.

First one is the table/model "Ad" (one) which is related to "AdEvent" (many). AdEvents has a foreign key "ad_id".

In the controller I can use it that way and it loads the related AdEvent-records.

```
$this->Ad->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array(
    'AdEvent' => array(
        'className'    => 'AdEvent',
        'foreignKey'   => 'ad_id',
    ))));
```

Now I just need the count without the data and I tried with param "fields" and "group" a COUNT()-statement, but in that case the result is empty. I also changed the relation to "hasOne", but no effect.

Any idea how to use the Cake-magic to do that?

EDIT:
With simple SQL it would look like this (I simplyfied it, a.id instead of a.*):

```
    SELECT a.id, COUNT(e.id) AS count_events
      FROM cake.admanager_ads AS a
      JOIN ad_events AS e ON e.ad_id = a.id
     GROUP BY a.id
     LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a manual count of course.  This is what I almost always end up doing because I almost always have the data loaded already for some other purpose.

```
$Ads = $this->Ad->find('all')
foreach ($Ads as $Ad) {
    $NumAdEvents = array(
        $Ad['Ad']['id'] => sizeof($Ad['AdEvents']),
    )
}
debug($NumAdEvents);
die;
```

Or you can use a find('count'):

```
$id_of_ad = 1; //insert your ad id here, or you can search by some other field
$NumAdEventsAtOneAd = $this->AdEvent->find('count', array('conditions' => array(
    'AdEvent.ad_id' => $id_of_ad,
)));
debug($NumAdEventsAtOneAd);
die;
```

Comment: The find('count') is what OP is looking for. A count of something is not an association, it's still just a number coming from your original model.

Comment: I know, but thats what I try to avoid, because a lot of unneeded data has to be loaded.

Comment: @oldskool: I need all data of "Ad" plus the count of the related "AdEvents". I could use a simple SQL query, but the requirement is to do it with cakemagic... :(

Comment: Dave, cake queries are genererally devided into two buckets: returning data (e.g. Ad titles and logos), or returning meta data (e.g. counts).  It will be quite ugly to get a single query that returns data in one model and a count in another.  What is your real need beyond the data?  Perhaps we can help rewrite your requirements.  I.e. are you optimizing for (1) simple code, (2) fast response, (3) few mysql queries, (4) other.  I have different solutions depending on your need.  'do it with cakemagic' is a little too vague.

Comment: So I cannot retrieve all data with one query? How can I sort a list of "Ads" in order to count of "AdEvents"?

Comment: You *can* retrieve all data with one query.  The find('all') I specified in the answer below does this.  To see what I'm talking about.  Insert a debug($Ads); somewhere and you'll see what I mean.  After that, it's just a question of how you want to display the data.  Running a sizeof() on an array is fine style to use.

Comment: There is no field "count" or something similar, even I put "COUNT(AdEvents.id) as count" in param "fields". There are all related AdEvents, but I don't want to count it in PHP.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to count it in PHP?

Comment: @therealtomrose: The reason why I won't count in PHP is, there is to much unneeded data and I only need a little integer. This is a job the database is made for.